# Entire screen not moving with the turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am making a game in python using the `turtle` module in python.
I want the screen to move with the turtle. Is there any way to do it? Thanks

Comment: The [`Canvas.yview_moveto()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.yview_moveto-method) method expects an argument in the range of 0.0 → 1.0, but you are passing it the `ball` turtle's y coordinate. I think maybe it should be something like `ts.yview_moveto(ball.ycor() / 10000)` given the size of your screen.

Comment: I tried using that but its just buggy.

Comment: Yes, I believe there are other problems with your code.

Comment: That was my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the screen isn't moving with the turtle ... Does
> anyone know why?

I know why.  First, @martineau is correct, as usual +1, about passing the wrong range of values to `yview_moveto()`.  But there's another piece to this puzzle: tkinter and turtle do not use the same coordinate system!  You need to correct for the coordinate system difference, then turn the value into a percentage.

Here's a stripped down example based on your code and desired behavior.  It keeps the ball in the middle of the window but you can tell from the numbers, and the vertical scroll bar, it's falling.  Tap the the up arrow to slow it down -- tap it again to stop the motion.  Tap it once more to start rising.  Or use the down arrow to reverse your movement again:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, DEPTH = 300, 10_000
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

vy = -10

def rise():
    global vy
    vy += 5

def fall():
    global vy
    vy -= 5

def move():
    global vy

    if abs(ball.ycor()) < DEPTH/2:
        ball.forward(vy)

        canvas.yview_moveto((DEPTH/2 - ball.ycor() - WIDTH/2 + CURSOR_SIZE) / DEPTH)

        screen.update()
        screen.ontimer(move)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, WIDTH)  # visible window
screen.screensize(WIDTH, DEPTH)  # area window peeps into
screen.tracer(False)

canvas = screen.getcanvas()

marker = Turtle()
marker.hideturtle()
marker.penup()
marker.setx(-WIDTH/4)  # so we can see we're moving

for y in range(-DEPTH//2, DEPTH//2, 100):
    marker.sety(y)
    marker.write(y, align='right')

ball = Turtle('circle')
ball.speed('fastest')
ball.setheading(90)
ball.penup()

screen.onkey(rise, 'Up')
screen.onkey(fall, 'Down')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's all good, but you need to explain more because currently I don't understand what anything means.

Comment: Can you explain more because the code works?

Comment: @JonathanDrukker, sure.  Which lines would you like explained?

Comment: The ones which have the screen movement in them.

Comment: And carculations

Comment: @JonathanDrukker, the `canvas.yview_moveto()` statement incorporates both, so let's break down its argument.  The `DEPTH/2 - ball.ycor()` is the y coordinate system translation from turtle's `DEPTH/2` to `-DEPTH/2` coordinates to tkinters `0` to `DEPTH` coordinates.  The `- WIDTH/2 + CURSOR_SIZE` centers the ball in the window, otherwise it appears at the very top.  The `/ DEPTH` is the conversion from pixels into a percentage of the window height, as @martineau described in his comment.

Comment: Just one more thing,can you explain to me how the yveiw moveto func works?

Comment: Can you thread the movement with movement on the X axis?