# Python Turtle centre turtle on screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to move the turtle in random directions while keeping the turtle at the center of the screen. How can I do this?

```
While True:
    turtle.setheading(random.randint(0,360))
    turtle.forward(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want the camera screen to follow the turtle whereever its going.

You can do this by manipulating the scroll position using methods of the underlying tkinter window structure.  Here's a turtle example that [moves a ball but keeps it centered in the window.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67260058/5771269)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "center of the screen"? Your code is turning your turtle by 0 to 360 and then move 10 forward. If you dont want to move the turtle remove the `turtle.forward(10)`.

To move your turtle back to the start you could add `turtle.home()`.

```
While True:
    turtle.setheading(random.randint(0,360))
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.home()
```

Comment: I want the camera screen to follow the turtle whereever its going.